# php array keyword counter

Tags: php, arrays, counter

I am pushing image file information into an array.
It is pretty simple except the keywords are sometimes an array also.
This works great for what I am doing now.
Here is a sample of my array

```
$list[]=array(filename=>$file,width=>$w,height=>$h,caption=>$iptc["2#120"],keywords=>$iptc["2#025"]);
```

I can use this array to output the html needed for a javascript slideshow.

```
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) { 
  while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
    if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ 
      //if this file is a valid image 
      $path = $dirname . "" . $file ; 
      $path2 = $dirname ."JPEG/" . $file ; 
      $size = getimagesize($path, $info); 
      $w = $size[0]; $h = $size[1]; 
      $iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']); 

      if(in_array($key,$iptc["2#025"])){
        $list[]=array(
          filename=>$file,
          width=>$w,
          height=>$h,
          caption=>$iptc["2#120"],
          keyw‌​ords=>$iptc["2#025"]
        ); 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  closedir($handle); }
```

I would like to be able to have another variable in the array which would count up one number as each unique keyword is added.  This will allow me to go directly to the middle of a slideshow as the js plugin I am using a js slideshow only have direct links if referenced by a number

I imagine I would need to create a unique array of all the keywords and then have some type of complicated if statement to count for each of the unique variables.....

however I have no Idea how to do this

Help Please

thanks

Jeremy

Comment: here is the complete code  (yes the code is in a loop)

Comment: if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
 while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
  if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
 
$path = $dirname . "" . $file ;
$path2 = $dirname ."JPEG/" . $file ;


   
$size = getimagesize($path, $info);
$w = $size[0];
$h = $size[1];
$iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);
   if(in_array($key,$iptc["2#025"])){ 
 $list[]=array(filename=>$file,width=>$w,height=>$h,caption=>$iptc["2#120"],keywords=>$iptc["2#025"]);
}
}
 }
 closedir($handle);
}

Comment: K, so the code is clear, thanks for that, I added it to the post, make sure you do that the next time ;) Your question isn't really clear on what _keywords_, _unique variables_ and the process of _counting up one number_ really have in common. You only add the image details to the `$list` if the key is in the `$iptc["2#05"]` array, where you also stated that this is _sometimes an array also_. Looking at your code, you always assume it's an array ... Hope you get what I'm saying? :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand what you're looking for but it sounds like:

```
while(loop_conditions){
    $list[]=array(filename=>$file,width=>$w,height=>$h,caption=>$iptc["2#120"],keywords=>$iptc["2#025"]);
    foreach($iptc["2#025"] as $keyword){
        $list_map[$keyword]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the example i submitted if a keyword is in the $iptc["2#025"] array it will be added to the array.

Comment: this is what I have working ( i should have left the if statement out of the array sample i sent) what I want to do is make an array of all the files and then have a counter which counts up for each unique keyword then when i choose one of the files i will be directed to a page which works as the above code with the if statement and starts with the file(counted keyword) of the file i chose.  My problem is if I were able to know all the keywords in advance I could make a series of if else statements for each keyword

Comment: I think I am getting closer... I run through the directory once create an array of all the keywords, then create an array of just the unique keywords    foreach ($iptc["2#025"] as $kw){
$keywords[]=$kw;}




sort($keywords);
$sorted = array_unique($keywords);

foreach($sorted as $keyword => $value) 
$sortedkey = array_values($sorted);   Now I want to run through the directory again and create an array of all the files with a key which counts up for each unique keyword